# How to upload/ deploy and organise the AWS CloudFormation templates when the templates are exporting values mutually

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am deploying my AWS resources using the CloudFormation templates. But I have two templates that are exporting and importing values from each other and using those values.

I have a template that uses the existing resources with the following template, called storage-resources.yml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Permanent resources to be imported"
Parameters:
  DBInstanceIdentifier:
    Type: String
    Default: 'patheindbidentifier'
  DBName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'patheindb'
  DBUsername:
    Type: String
    Default: 'patheindbadmin'
  DBClass:
    Type: String
    Default: 'db.t2.micro'
  DBAllocatedStorage:
    Type: String
    Default: '5'
  DBPassword:
    Type: String

Resources:
  StorageBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: pathein-directory-storage
      AccessControl: PublicRead

  DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Database security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3306'
          ToPort: '3306'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !ImportValue PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId

  WebDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Ref DBInstanceIdentifier
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      DBInstanceClass: !Ref DBClass
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBPassword
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt DBSecurityGroup.GroupId

Outputs:
  StorageBucket:
    Description: "S3 storage bucket"
    Value: !Ref StorageBucket
    Export:
      Name: PatheinStorageBucket
```

As you can see in the template above, I am exporting the S3 bucket. Another thing is that I am importing a resource and using it as follow.

```
!ImportValue PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

Basically the PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup is in another template called core.yml. I am also importing the S3 bucket from the resources.yml template into the core.yml template.

Now, what I am trying to do is that I am trying to deploy resources.yml using the option that uses the existing resources. But the problem is that I cannot upload it and it throws the error when I did because the core.yml template does not exist yet and it is using the PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup from the core.yml template.

What is the best way to upload or deploy the templates in this scenario? I am even doing the right thing? How can I do it better?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a circular dependency? `core.yml` imports something from `resources.yml`, while at the same time `resources.yml` imports from `core.yml`?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, yes. Exactly. I was just struggling to find the right term.

Comment: I see. In this case you would have to create a third template to break the circular dependency. Do you have an example of `core.yaml` which imports from `resources.yml`?

Comment: Actually, there is a db security group in the resources.yml which is referencing the web security group in the core.yml. In the core.yml, I am referencing the S3 bucket which is in the resources.yml. In terms of example, template, I am still trying to create it. Dummy template could work too. I can just reference on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Since you have **circular dependency** between your templates, the **easiest solution** would be to move the `StorageBucket` from `resources.yml` into `core.yml`, and then export it from there. This way in `resources.yml` you would import both `PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup` and `StorageBucket`.

The alternative is to move `StorageBucket` and `PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup` into third template, thus breaking the circular dependency.

Also note that you can't do:

```
!ImportValue PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

As an example, you can have the following two templates with circular dependency ( had to create my own example core.yml):

**core.yml**

```
Resources:


  MyELB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
    Properties: 
      AccessLoggingPolicy: 
        #EmitInterval: Integer
        Enabled: true
        S3BucketName: !ImportValue PatheinStorageBucket
        #S3BucketPrefix: String
      Listeners:
        - InstancePort: 80
          LoadBalancerPort: 80
          Protocol: HTTP
 
  PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Database security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3306'
          ToPort: '3306'
          CidrIp: 10.0.0.0/16


Outputs:

  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Description: "Security Group"
    Value: !Ref PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup
```

**resource.yml**

```
Resources:

  StorageBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    #DeletionPolicy: Retain
    #UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: pathein-directory-storage-332112
      AccessControl: PublicRead

  DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Database security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3306'
          ToPort: '3306'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !ImportValue PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId


Outputs:
  StorageBucket:
    Description: "S3 storage bucket"
    Value: !Ref StorageBucket
    Export:
      Name: PatheinStorageBucket
```

To solve the above problem, you can create a third template which defines `StorageBucket` and `PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup`:

**base.yml**

```
Resources:

  StorageBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    #DeletionPolicy: Retain
    #UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: pathein-directory-storage-332112
      AccessControl: PublicRead

  PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Database security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3306'
          ToPort: '3306'
          CidrIp: 10.0.0.0/16

Outputs:

  StorageBucket:
    Description: "S3 storage bucket"
    Value: !Ref StorageBucket
    Export:
      Name: PatheinStorageBucket


  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Description: "Security Group"
    Value: !GetAtt PatheinWebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId
    Export:
      Name: PatheinWebServerSecurityGroupId
```

Then core.yml and resource.yml would be:

**core.yml**

```
Resources:

  MyELB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
    Properties: 
      AccessLoggingPolicy: 
        #EmitInterval: Integer
        Enabled: true
        S3BucketName: !ImportValue PatheinStorageBucket
        #S3BucketPrefix: String
      Listeners:
        - InstancePort: 80
          LoadBalancerPort: 80
          Protocol: HTTP
      AvailabilityZones: !GetAZs ""
```

**resource.yml**

```
Resources:

  DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Database security group
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3306'
          ToPort: '3306'
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !ImportValue PatheinWebServerSecurityGroupId
```

Comment: So the deployment process would be base.yml -> resources.yml -> core.yml?

Comment: @WaiYanHein Yes. `base.yml` must be first, as the others import its outputs.

Comment: @WaiYanHein No problem :-)